# date in the picture can you check that the sotała has changed?

Tags: jpeg, exiftool

I would like to check if the date in the photo has been changed, if someone can do it.I can't find much on the internet about it.

Comment: What does the word "sotała" in the title mean?

Answer (score 3):

Short: **You can't be sure**

You can check the date with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -T -DateTimeOriginal -FileName <filename>
```

But you can't be sure this date is not changed. The only case which can give you some doubts is when the date in image is newer related to the date of image file. But all those dates (file and EXIF/etc) can be changed w/o any trace.

Answer (score -2):

I found- in hexadecimal and ASCII format and reveal things like strings with the name of the application or library library. If you are a developer, you can always get the specification of the JPEG format and manually analyze the data in the file after taking the hexadecimal dump and see if anything useful is revealed - I am not a programmer unfortunately.

Comment: WIth the name of application you get only the fact the photo is edited (eventually). But you can't be 100% sure even in this

Comment: :( Thank You, for the answers.